# Change all buttons backgroundColor made in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im doing a function(**clearGame**) to change all backgroundColor of the numbers i get in "NumbersParent". I tried using querySelector but all i get is "null" from changeStyle.

```
const newBet: React.FC = () => {

  const clearGame = () => {
    let spliceRangeJSON = gamesJson[whichLoteriaIsVar].range;
    for (let i = 0; i <= spliceRangeJSON; i++) {
      const changeStyle = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('data-key');
      changeStyle!.style.backgroundColor = '#ADC0C4';
    }
  };

  const NumbersParent = (props: any) => {
    const [numbersColor, setNumbersColor] = useState('#ADC0C4');
    const changeButtonColor = () => {
      if (numbersColor === '#ADC0C4') {
        setNumbersColor(gamesJson[whichLoteriaIsVar].color);
      } else {
        setNumbersColor('#ADC0C4');
      }
    };
    return (
      <Numbers
        color={numbersColor}
        onClick={changeButtonColor}
      >
        {props.children}
      </Numbers>
    );
  };

} return(
        <NumbersContainer>
          {numbersList.map((num) => (
            <NumbersParent key={num} id={num} data-key={num}>
              {num}
            </NumbersParent>
          ))}
        </NumbersContainer>
        <Button onClick={clearGame}>Clear Game</Button
)
```

Comment: Don't try to manipulate the dom inside a react app. All changes should be made to the react components, then react will update the dom. React cannot track changes to the dom made outside of the components.

Comment: You can initialize 2 kind of buttons and use state to control which kind of button appears on the screen.